# Проблема с Django

Tags: python, django, backend

Я пытаюсь вывести сетку товаров, но django ругается

```
ValueError at /
The view shop.views.ProductList didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view shop.views.ProductList didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Star\PycharmProjects\Shop_NEW\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 126
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Star\PycharmProjects\Shop_NEW\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Star\\PycharmProjects\\Shop_NEW',
 'C:\\Users\\Star\\PycharmProjects\\Shop_NEW',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.1.3\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
 'C:\\Users\\Star\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Star\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Star\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Star\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Star\\PycharmProjects\\Shop_NEW\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\Star\\PycharmProjects\\Shop_NEW\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Star\\PycharmProjects\\Shop_NEW\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\Star\\PycharmProjects\\Shop_NEW\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2019.1.3\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Fri, 5 Jul 2019 10:08:38 +0000
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$',views.ProductList, name="ProductListbyCategory"),
    re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.ProductDetail, name = 'ProductDetail'),
    re_path(r'^$', views.ProductList , name = "ProfuctList")
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from  .models import Product, Category

def ProductList(reqeust, category_slug = None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug = category_slug)
        products = products.filter(Category = category)
        return render(reqeust, 'shop/product/list.html', {'category': category,
                                                         'categories': categories,
                                                         'products': products})


def ProductDetail(request,id,slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,id= id, slug = slug, available = True)
    return  render(request, 'shop/product/detail.html', {'product': product})
```

**list.html**

```
{% extends 'shop/wrapper.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
     {% if category %}
        {{ category.name }}
         {% else %}
         Страница Товаров
     {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
 <div id="sidebar" class="col-sm-3">
    <h3>Категории</h3>
    <ul>
      <li {% if not category %} class="selected" {% endif %}>
        <a href="{% url "shop:ProductList" %}">Все</a>
      </li>
      {% for cat in categories %}
        <li {% if category.slug == cat.slug %} class="selected" {% endif %}>
          <a href="{{ cat.get_absolute_url }}">{{ cat.name }}</a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="main" class="product_list col-sm-9">
    <h1>{% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Товары{% endif %}</h1>
    <div class="items row">
      {% for product in products %}
        <div class="item col-sm-4">
          <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
            <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no-image.jpg"%}{% endif %}" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
          <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a><br>
          {{ product.price }} руб.
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Если `category_slug == None`, то `ProductList` возвращает `None`. Вам нужно сделать так, чтобы и в этом случае возвращалось что-то.

Comment: если category_slug == None, вызывайте исключение `raise Http404`

Comment: и совет использовать generic views